# What type of algorithm would be appropriate here?

Tags: algorithm

I need to design an algorithm for solving the following problem:

> Consider a straight line L in the plane. A finite set T of targets are located above the line L, and a finite set S of wireless sensors are located below the line L. A sensor s can monitor a target t if and only if the Euclidean distance between s and t is at most one. Suppose that each sensor s ∈ S has a positive cost c (s) and each target t ∈ T can be monitored by at least one sensor in S. Consider a subset S0 of sensors in S. S0 is said to be a cover if each target in T is covered by at least one sensor in S0. The cost of S0 is the total costs of the sensors in S0. The objective is to compute a cover S0 of minimum cost. Please develop a polynomial time algorithm and write a program to implement it.

I really don't know which type of algorithm I could use for this (greedy, dynamic, divide and conquer) I'm not looking necessarily for an answer as much as a hint on how to proceed. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Is this a "vertex cover" problem?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title so that it will be useful to others.

Answer (score 3):

Look at here http://www.pressingquestion.com/3830657/Computing-Minimum-Cost-With-Using-Dynamic-Programming. That is a question very similar to yours. The solution of that question indicates your question is NP-Hard, rather than polynomial. However, if you slightly change your question in the way that those targets are **on** the line rather than **above** the line, then you can use a *dynamic programming* approach to solve it. Details are provided in the link.

If your question is not changed, and you still want a polynomial solution, then may be you need an assumption that the sensors are placed in a *sparse* way. In this case, you can use a *divide-and-conquer* approach. Sort all sensors in the direction of the line (suppose the line L is the x-axis, then sort sensors by their x-ordinate), then divide them from the middle. When dividing, you need to reason about those points whose x-ordinate is near (no further than 1) from where you divide very carefully. If too many points are there, the algorithm will not be polynomial, and that is why a sparse assumption is needed.

Comment: That's a very interesting link, because I remember writing that text in stackoverflow. I can't find it there with Google, but searching for that text finds both your link and http://www.rqna.net/qna/iixzzr-computing-minimum-cost-with-using-dynamic-programming-closed.html - this is the first time I have heard of either of these sites. A google search on the question at the top of the link gives me a search results view of the start of it as a highest voted question, but the link from the search results does not go to the question. Anybody know what these sites are?

Comment: If you follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189050/computing-minimum-cost-with-using-dynamic-programming you can see that the question was moderated out of StackOverflow. FWIW I don't think it matters that the targets are over the line: each target gives rise to an interval on a line where a centre can see it and the same sort of dynamic programming approach will work - in fact my only uncertainty is whether there is a faster greedy approach which will also work.

Comment: @mcdowella I don't think so. When some targets are near the line, and some others are far away (but no further than 1) from the line, then what a sensor can cover is not guaranteed to be a range, but instead, a set, which makes the problem complicated. I thought a simple DP approach will work too from the first glance, but later I found it wrong.

Comment: "Details are provided in the link" - can you provide them in your answer as well? We don't particularly like answers being dependent on external links.

Comment: @jeffrey the set of positions from which a sensor could see a particular target is an interval. So we can reduce the problem to finding the minimum number of points on the line such that each interval has at least one point in it. The start and end points of each interval cut the line into segments and within each such smallest segment it does not matter where you put a point. So use DP to find the smallest number of segments that must receive a point to cover every interval.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will probably try both. You helped a lot thank you.